# Using apache for dns blocking page and removing all jargon in URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, dns

I have a little DNS Spoofing / Blocking system I setup for work. It simply uses a blacklist to spoof the dns records and simply points them to a BLOCK / DENY page.

If I go to the URL directly for instance http://www.redtube.com the system works as expected and displays my index.html and what it should

The problem arises if I go to http://www.redtube.com/video?/43 or anything other than the full domain I get a not found.

I need to to configure Apache so that it drops all the junk after the TLD and simply displays my page such as http://blocked.project.com

Another way to look at it would be to say redirect to index.html if the url entered is not known to the webserver.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Used an apache FallbackResource to achieve exactly what I was after. Had to make sure my image paths on the website were absolute but works a treat.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource